# Confusion with Moonshado Heroku Add-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sms, heroku

According to [this documention](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moonshadosms), it seems as if Moonshado will automatically route any mobile-originated SMS message to your application if it contains the first word as your keyword. I do not understand how this is possible. Any SMS message in the US that contains the first word as your keyword will be routed to your app? How is it possible for Moonshado to read every message? There must be something I'm not getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SMS messages originating in the US, any messages sent to 69940 containing your keyword as the first word, will be routed to your application.

So if you want your users to be able to send SMS messages to you application, you need to tell them to SMS your keyword to '69940'.

It mentions it *very* briefly at the bottom of the documentation:

#### Further reading:

- US incoming SMS ShortCode is 69940 (International MO support coming soon)

Comment: ahh thanks dude, yeah they really mention it ever so briefly, it should be more obvious in the documentation